# Excel evaluate() returning object[,]?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am writing a shortkey event handler to implement activity when the user types in a function and then presses a keyboard shortcut.

As I understand `ExcelApp.Evaluate("myFunc()")` is the way to go.

However, within my XLL Addin, myFunc returns type `object[,]` whereas `Evaluate()` only returns type object

Is there any way I can convert `object` to `object[,]`?

EDIT:

```
object myArray = ExcelApp.Evaluate(functioname);

if (myArray is object[,])
{
    int height = myArray.GetLength(0); //Does not recognise GetLength, even though it's an object[,] method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Evaluate` may be the way to go, or it may be not, depending on what exactly you want.
If you want to actually evaluate things like addresses, then yes, it is.
Otherwise, there's `Application.Run`.

As for the question, Excel's functions return `OLE Variant`, which may contain/refer to anything, including an array. From Excel side, handling this does not require any effort from the code.

EDIT:

```
object[,] foo = (object[,])this.Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(new object[] {1,2,3,4} );

MessageBox.Show ( foo.GetLength(0).ToString() );  // shows 4
```

Comment: Basically I want to execute UDFs where the return type is object[,] but evaluate only returns type 'object'..

Comment: It returns `object` that points to `object[,]`. There's no problem.

Comment: but when I call myObject.GetLength(0) (for the range perimeter) it's not recognising the member function GetLength because it see's myObject as an object?